# Why would peaks of absorption spectra follow a Gaussian distribution?

Tags: spectroscopy, absorption

I'm working on some code that is used for hyperspectral analysis.

In the older version of the code there were two main approaches taken when extracting features from the hyperspectral absorption spectra. One was by fitting a polynomial to the curve and extracting the minima/maxima of the resulting function.

The second approach that's currently being used is fitting a Gaussian to the spectral peaks.

And here I am confused. I don't understand why would a peak of an absorption spectrum be described using a function that describes a distribution of a random variable?

Is using the Gaussian a correct approach or some other method should be used instead?

Comment: In what context?

Comment: Many absorption features are, indeed, Gaussian. Learning why this is will be of great help in understanding hyperspectral techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The peaks will have an approximately Gaussian shape if the peak width is dominated by Doppler broadening and it will have an approximately Lorentzian shape if it's determined by lifetime broadening. In most cases Doppler broadening dominates so a Gaussian is a good option for fitting.

The Doppler broadening is due to the random thermal velocities of the gas molecules (or whatever is doing the emitting) so that's where the *random variable* that you ask about comes from.

I have to say that in my experience of fitting spectra it doesn't matter exactly what shape you use unless you're doing really high precision work. If you just want the peak position and half width any roughly Gaussian shaped function will do.